# Google Tag Manager Android - JSONArrays are not supported

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098881/google-tag-manager-v4-binary-download-container) and I'm using Google Tag Manager for Android v5.

```
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:9.4.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.4.0 (*)
```

The container is live and I downloaded the JSON file.

I'm using [this approach](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/TagManager) instead of putting the JSON file in `/assets/containers/` because I need to configure the Google Analytics property at runtime
(I have 2 GA properties, one production and 1 test one)

My launcher activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Logger.d("onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        initGTM();
    }
    private void initGTM() {
        TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        PendingResult pending = tagManager. loadContainerPreferNonDefault(
                "GTM_XXXABC",
                R.raw.gtm_xxxabc);
        ContainerHolder containerHolder = (ContainerHolder) pending.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String value = containerHolder.getContainer().getString("myKey");
        Logger.w("status is " + containerHolder.getStatus());

        DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDataLayer();
        dataLayer.pushEvent("openScreen", DataLayer.mapOf("screenName", "Main Page"));
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
02-02 22:54:49.708 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                     Process: com.xxx.digital.staging, PID: 21101
                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.digital.staging/com.xxx.digital.views.activities.SplashActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: JSONArrays are not supported
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JSONArrays are not supported
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzbg.zzaj(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzbg.zzaj(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzbg.zzaj(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzbg.zzai(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzbg.zzox(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcu.zza(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcu.zzze(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzp.zzcaq(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.TagManager.loadContainerDefaultOnly(Unknown Source)
                                         at com.xxx.digital.views.activities.SplashActivity.initGTM(SplashActivity.java:105)
                                         at com.xxx.digital.views.activities.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:70)
                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

R.raw.xxxabc:

```
{

"fingerprint":"Ng$0",

"resource": {
  "version":"6",
  "macros":[
    {
      "function":"__e",
      "instance_name":"Event Name",
      "vendor_template_version":"1"
    },
    {
      "function":"__md",
      "instance_name":"price",
      "vendor_template_version":"1",
      "vtp_setDefaultValue":false,
      "vtp_eventType":"CUSTOM",
      "vtp_key":"price"
    },
    {
      "function":"__md",
      "instance_name":"card number",
      "vendor_template_version":"1",
      "vtp_setDefaultValue":false,
      "vtp_eventType":"CUSTOM",
      "vtp_key":"card_number"
    },
    ...
"runtime":
[[50,"__ai_main",[46],[36,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"applicationId",[7]]]],[50,"__ai",[46,"data"],[36,["__ai_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"__an_main",[46],[36,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"applicationName",[7]]]],[50,"__an",[46,"data"],[36,["__an_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"__av_main",[46],[36,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"applicationVersion",[7]]]],[50,"__av",[46,"data"],[36,["__av_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"__c_main",[46,"a"],[36,[17,[15,"a"],"value"]]],[50,"__c",[46,"data"],[36,["__c_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"__e_main",[46],[41,"a","b"],[3,"a",[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"event",[7]]],[22,[1,[1,[15,"a"],[18,[17,[15,"a"],"length"],0]],[12,[16,[15,"a"],0],"_"]],[46,[3,"b",[8,"_f","first_open","_iap","in_app_purchase","_e","user_engagement","_s","session_start","_au","app_update","_ui","app_remove","_ou","os_update","_cd","app_clear_data","_ae","app_exception","_nf","notification_foreground","_nr","notification_receive","_no","notification_open","_nd","notification_dismiss","_cmp","firebase_campaign"]],[3,"a",[30,[16,[15,"b"],[15,"a"]],[15,"a"]]]]],[36,[15,"a"]]],[50,"__e",[46,"data"],[36,["__e_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"__ua_main",[46,"a"],[41,"b","c","d"],[3,"b",["__ua_convertFieldsToSet",[17,[15,"a"],"fieldsToSet"]]],[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026tid",[17,[15,"a"],"trackingId"]],[3,"c","screenview"],[3,"d",true],[38,[17,[15,"a"],"trackType"],[46,"TRACK_EVENT","TRACK_EXCEPTION","TRACK_SOCIAL","TRACK_TIMING","TRACK_TRANSACTION"],[46,[5,[46,[3,"c","event"],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"eventCategory"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026ec",[17,[15,"a"],"eventCategory"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"eventAction"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026ea",[17,[15,"a"],"eventAction"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"eventLabel"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026el",[17,[15,"a"],"eventLabel"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"eventValue"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026ev",[17,[15,"a"],"eventValue"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"nonInteraction"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026ni",[17,[15,"a"],"nonInteraction"]]]],[22,[17,[15,"a"],"enableFirebaseCampaignData"],[46,["__ua_convertCampaignParams",[15,"b"],[17,[15,"a"],"sendFirebaseCampaignData"]]]],[4]]],[5,[46,[3,"c","exception"],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"exceptionDescription"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026exd",[17,[15,"a"],"exceptionDescription"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"exceptionFatal"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026exf",[17,[15,"a"],"exceptionFatal"]]]],[4]]],[5,[46,[3,"c","social"],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"socialNetwork"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026sn",[17,[15,"a"],"socialNetwork"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"socialAction"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026sa",[17,[15,"a"],"socialAction"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"socialActionTarget"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026st",[17,[15,"a"],"socialActionTarget"]]]],[4]]],[5,[46,[3,"c","timing"],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"timingVar"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026utv",[17,[15,"a"],"timingVar"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"timingCategory"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026utc",[17,[15,"a"],"timingCategory"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"timingValue"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026utt",[17,[15,"a"],"timingValue"]]]],[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"timingLabel"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026utl",[17,[15,"a"],"timingLabel"]]]],[4]]],[5,[46,[3,"c","transaction"],[3,"d",false],[4]]]]],[43,[15,"b"],"\u0026t",[15,"c"]],[22,[17,[15,"a"],"dimension"],[46,["__ua_convertIndexedField",[15,"b"],[17,[15,"a"],"dimension"],"\u0026cd","index","dimension"]]],[22,[17,[15,"a"],"metric"],[46,["__ua_convertIndexedField",[15,"b"],[17,[15,"a"],"metric"],"\u0026cm","index","metric"]]],[22,[17,[15,"a"],"contentGroup"],[46,["__ua_convertIndexedField",[15,"b"],[17,[15,"a"],"contentGroup"],"\u0026cg","index","group"]]],[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"universalAnalytics",[7,[15,"b"],[15,"d"],[12,[15,"c"],"transaction"],[44],[44],[17,[15,"a"],"enableEcommerce"],[17,[15,"a"],"useEcommerceDataLayer"],[17,[15,"a"],"ecommerceMacroData"],[17,[15,"a"],"collectAdid"]]]],[50,"__ua_convertFieldsToSet",[46,"a"],[41,"b","c","d","e","f","g","h"],[22,[28,[15,"a"]],[46,[36,[8]]]],[3,"b",[8,"account","\u0026tid","anonymizeIp","\u0026aip","appName","\u0026an","appVersion","\u0026av","firebaseCampaignAdNetworkClickId","\u0026aclid","firebaseCampaignAdNetworkId","\u0026anid","firebaseCampaignContent","\u0026cc","firebaseCampaignGoogleClickId","\u0026gclid","firebaseCampaignMedium","\u0026cm","firebaseCampaignName","\u0026cn","firebaseCampaignSource","\u0026cs","firebaseCampaignTerm","\u0026ck","contentDescription","\u0026cd","contentGroup","\u0026cg","dimension","\u0026cd","eventAction","\u0026ea","eventCategory","\u0026ec","eventLabel","\u0026el","eventValue","\u0026ev","exceptionDescription","\u0026exd","exceptionFatal","\u0026exf","metric","\u0026cm","noninteraction","\u0026ni","page","\u0026dp","referrer","\u0026dr","sampleRate","\u0026sf","screenName","\u0026cd","sessionControl","\u0026sc","socialAction","\u0026sa","socialActionTarget","\u0026st","socialNetwork","\u0026sn","timingCategory","\u0026utc","timingLabel","\u0026utl","timingValue","\u0026utt","timingVar","\u0026utv","title","\u0026dt"]],[3,"c",[7,"\u0026tid","\u0026aip","\u0026an","\u0026av","\u0026cd","\u0026cg","\u0026cd","\u0026ea","\u0026ec","\u0026el","\u0026ev","\u0026exd","\u0026exf","\u0026cm","\u0026ni","\u0026dp","\u0026dr","\u0026sf","\u0026cd","\u0026sc","\u0026sa","\u0026st","\u0026sn","\u0026utc","\u0026utl","\u0026utt","\u0026utv","\u0026dt"]],[3,"d",[8]],[3,"e",0],[42,[23,[15,"e"],[17,[15,"a"],"length"]],[33,[15,"e"],[3,"e",[0,[15,"e"],1]]],false,[46,[3,"f",[16,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"e"]],"fieldName"]],[3,"g",[16,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"e"]],"value"]],[22,[1,[21,[15,"g"],[44]],[21,[15,"g"],[45]]],[46,[3,"h",[16,[15,"b"],[15,"f"]]],[22,[21,[15,"h"],[44]],[46,[43,[15,"d"],[15,"h"],[15,"g"]]],[46,[22,[19,[2,[15,"c"],"indexOf",[7,[15,"f"]]],0],[46,[43,[15,"d"],[15,"f"],[15,"g"]]]]]]]]]],[36,[15,"d"]]],[50,"__ua_convertIndexedField",[46,"a","b","c","d","e"],[41,"f","g"],[3,"f",0],[42,[23,[15,"f"],[17,[15,"b"],"length"]],[33,[15,"f"],[3,"f",[0,[15,"f"],1]]],false,[46,[3,"g",[16,[15,"b"],[15,"f"]]],[43,[15,"a"],[0,[15,"c"],[16,[15,"g"],[15,"d"]]],[16,[15,"g"],[15,"e"]]]]]],[50,"__ua_convertCampaignParams",[46,"a","b"],[41,"c","d","e"],[22,[21,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"event",[7]],"_cmp"],[46,[36]]],[3,"c",[30,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"eventParameters",[7]],[8]]],[22,[15,"b"],[46,[3,"d",[8,"content","\u0026cc","anid","\u0026anid","medium","\u0026cm","campaign","\u0026cn","source","\u0026cs","term","\u0026ck","gclid","\u0026gclid","aclid","\u0026aclid"]]],[46,[3,"d",[8,"anid","\u0026anid","gclid","\u0026gclid","aclid","\u0026aclid"]]]],[47,"e",[15,"d"],[46,[22,[1,[16,[15,"c"],[15,"e"]],[28,[2,[15,"a"],"hasOwnProperty",[7,[16,[15,"d"],[15,"e"]]]]]],[46,[43,[15,"a"],[16,[15,"d"],[15,"e"]],[16,[15,"c"],[15,"e"]]]]]]]],[50,"__ua",[46,"data"],[36,["__ua_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"__md_main",[46,"a"],[41,"b","c","d","e"],[22,[12,[17,[15,"a"],"eventType"],"CUSTOM"],[46,[3,"b",[16,[15,"a"],"key"]]],[46,[22,[12,[17,[15,"a"],"eventType"],"SUGGESTED"],[46,[47,"c",[15,"a"],[46,[3,"d",[2,[15,"c"],"lastIndexOf",[7,"Param"]]],[22,[1,[29,[15,"d"],[27,1]],[12,[15,"d"],[37,[17,[15,"c"],"length"],5]]],[46,[22,[20,[15,"b"],[44]],[46,[3,"b",[16,[15,"a"],[15,"c"]]]],[46,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"log",[7,"e",[0,[0,[0,"Ignoring unexpected additional parameter ","key in the data (key \u003d \""],[15,"c"]],"\")."]]]]]]]]]],[46,[22,[20,[17,[15,"a"],"eventType"],[44]],[46,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"log",[7,"w","Missing expected eventType param"]],[3,"b",[16,[15,"a"],"key"]]],[46,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"log",[7,"e",[0,"Unexpected eventType param value: ",[17,[15,"a"],"eventType"]]]],[36]]]]]]],[22,[20,[15,"b"],[44]],[46,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"log",[7,"e","No parameter key specified in the data."]],[36]]],[3,"e",[16,[30,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"mobile"],"eventParameters",[7]],[8]],[15,"b"]]],[22,[21,[15,"e"],[44]],[46,[36,[15,"e"]]],[46,[22,[21,[17,[15,"a"],"defaultValue"],[44]],[46,[36,[17,[15,"a"],"defaultValue"]]],[46,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"log",[7,"w",[0,[0,"Event does not have parameter \"",[15,"b"]],"\" and no default value was defined. Returning \"undefined\"."]]]]]]]],[50,"__md",[46,"data"],[36,["__md_main",[15,"data"]]]],
[50,"main",[46,"a"],[43,[17,[15,"a"],"common"],"tableToMap",[15,"tableToMap"]],[43,[17,[15,"a"],"common"],"stringify",[15,"stringify"]]],[50,"tableToMap",[46,"a","b","c"],[41,"d","e","f"],[3,"d",[8]],[3,"e",false],[3,"f",0],[42,[1,[15,"a"],[23,[15,"f"],[17,[15,"a"],"length"]]],[33,[15,"f"],[3,"f",[0,[15,"f"],1]]],false,[46,[22,[1,[1,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"f"]],[2,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"f"]],"hasOwnProperty",[7,[15,"b"]]]],[2,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"f"]],"hasOwnProperty",[7,[15,"c"]]]],[46,[43,[15,"d"],[16,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"f"]],[15,"b"]],[16,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"f"]],[15,"c"]]],[3,"e",true]]]]],[36,[39,[15,"e"],[15,"d"],[45]]]],[50,"stringify",[46,"a"],[41,"b","c","d","e"],[22,[20,[15,"a"],[45]],[46,[36,"null"]]],[22,[20,[15,"a"],[44]],[46,[36,[44]]]],[22,[30,[12,[40,[15,"a"]],"number"],[12,[40,[15,"a"]],"boolean"]],[46,[36,[2,[15,"a"],"toString",[7]]]]],[22,[12,[40,[15,"a"]],"string"],[46,[36,[0,[0,"\"",[2,["split",[15,"a"],"\""],"join",[7,"\\\""]]],"\""]]]],[22,[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"isArray",[7,[15,"a"]]],[46,[3,"b",[7]],[3,"c",0],[42,[23,[15,"c"],[17,[15,"a"],"length"]],[33,[15,"c"],[3,"c",[0,[15,"c"],1]]],false,[46,[3,"d",["stringify",[16,[15,"a"],[15,"c"]]]],[22,[12,[15,"d"],[44]],[46,[2,[15,"b"],"push",[7,"null"]]],[46,[2,[15,"b"],"push",[7,[15,"d"]]]]]]],[36,[0,[0,"[",[2,[15,"b"],"join",[7,","]]],"]"]]]],[22,[12,[40,[15,"a"]],"object"],[46,[3,"b",[7]],[47,"e",[15,"a"],[46,[3,"d",["stringify",[16,[15,"a"],[15,"e"]]]],[22,[29,[15,"d"],[44]],[46,[2,[15,"b"],"push",[7,[0,[0,[0,"\"",[15,"e"]],"\":"],[15,"d"]]]]]]]],[36,[0,[0,"{",[2,[15,"b"],"join",[7,","]]],"}"]]]],[2,[17,[15,"gtmUtils"],"common"],"log",[7,"e","Attempting to stringify unknown type!"]],[36,[44]]],[50,"split",[46,"a","b"],[41,"c","d","e","f"],[3,"c",[7]],[22,[20,[15,"b"],""],[46,[3,"d",[17,[15,"a"],"length"]],[3,"e",0],[42,[23,[15,"e"],[15,"d"]],[33,[15,"e"],[3,"e",[0,[15,"e"],1]]],false,[46,[2,[15,"c"],"push",[7,[16,[15,"a"],[15,"e"]]]]]],[36,[15,"c"]]]],[42,[1,[15,"a"],[19,[2,[15,"a"],"indexOf",[7,[15,"b"]]],0]],[46],false,[46,[3,"f",[2,[15,"a"],"indexOf",[7,[15,"b"]]]],[22,[12,[15,"f"],0],[46,[2,[15,"c"],"push",[7,""]]],[46,[2,[15,"c"],"push",[7,[2,[15,"a"],"substring",[7,0,[15,"f"]]]]]]],[3,"a",[2,[15,"a"],"substring",[7,[0,[15,"f"],[17,[15,"b"],"length"]]]]]]],[2,[15,"c"],"push",[7,[15,"a"]]],[36,[15,"c"]]]]
}
```

Google Tag Manager container:
[image]

Comment: u are downloading binary container not json one?

Comment: what do you mean @NayanSrivastava, `R.raw.gtm_xxxabc` is a JSON file here

Comment: Added my answer, check if this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a **Legacy** container solved the problem. I was able to download the binary file as someone mentioned here.

The container I was using is the new **Firebase** kind which only works with the JSON file.

Nevertheless, we found an even easier way of achieving dynamic GA property. In the *Universal Analytics* settings,m the GA property ID can be variable - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6163791?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `JSON` file, you need to add `binary` file. You can download it by clicking on your `live version of container`, then in the right top you will get the option to download the file, replace this file with your `JSON` file and you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: how is your screenshot different from mine above @NayanSrivastava? When I clicked "Download" I got the JSON file. What is the extension of your binary file btw, or no extension?

Comment: no extension, ideally I would suggest create a testing container and then download it. It should be binary file

Comment: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/#default-container, read point 2. Adding a Default Container File to your Project